# What is the correct query for a Doctrine ODM Geospatial query?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, geospatial

I've set up a classes as described at
http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/mongodb_odm/1.0/en/reference/geospatial-queries.html

My 2d index is set correctly in mongo

```
> db.system.indexes.find()                                          
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "pfcd_dev.media", "name" : "_id_" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "pfcd_dev.events", "name" : "_id_" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "coordinates" : "2d" }, "ns" : "pfcd_dev.events", "name" : "coordinates_" }
```

When I run the following command on the mongo shell, I get numerous results returned.

```
db.runCommand( { geoNear : "events" , near : [50,60], num : 10 } )
```

I've tried all the following variations for `near()`, all return zero results

```
$places = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('\Application\Event')->field('coordinates')->near('[50,60]')->getQuery()->execute();
$places = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('\Application\Event')->field('coordinates')->near('50,60')->getQuery()->execute();
$places = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('\Application\Event')->field('coordinates')->near(50,60)->getQuery()->execute();
$places = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('\Application\Event')->field('coordinates')->near(array(50,60))->getQuery()->execute();
```

The documentation on Doctrine's site seems to be a bit off. Just for record, I've created a gist showing my classes (trucated). https://gist.github.com/1627491

This is the output of `debug()`

```
$this->dm->createQueryBuilder('\Application\Event')->field('coordinates')->near('50,60')->debug();

    Array
    (
        [type] => 10
        [mapReduce] => Array
            (
                [map] => 
                [reduce] => 
                [options] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [near] => Array
            (
                [coordinates] => 50,60
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried getting rid of your `extends Base` for your models?

You also might try something like:

```
$places = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('\Application\Event')->field('coordinates.latitude')->near(50)->field('coordinates.longitude')->near(60)->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: I have not tried removing the extends Base, but I'm curious as to why that would affect the outcome of the query. Base is an Abstract class I made just to handle some simple operations common to all models. I'm able to run other queries against ODM with stellar success.

Comment: You've earned yourself +50 rep points that I am glad to give. The solution you provided worked perfectly. Take the rest of the day off.

Comment: To be more clear, the query worked great, but I did NOT get rid or `extends Base`

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that if the Base class had other attributes, the driver might not know which attributes were related to the 2d index. Then I found a way to specify which attributes you want to use, which is apparently the right way.